# Installing htmltools in R gives me unable to load shared object libimf.so

Tags: r, rlang, htmltools

When I try to install htmltools using this command:

```
install.packages("htmltools")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/gscratch/jayadevlab/packages/r/rlang/libs/rlang.so':
  libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load
```

I am running R version 3.6.3 on a server with CentOS7.
This uses an intel compiler by default, but I have also tried using gcc-8.2.1 with the same result. I do not have super user access on this server.

I am new to all of this, so any help would be appreciated.